# DDD - Deriving Value Object From Entity

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm pretty new to DDD and as always when you wrap your head around interesting concepts you'll inevitably reach a point or a situation which makes you feel uncertain about how consequent the stuff you just learned should be applied facing certain problems.

Say you have two different Dates concerning users: `DateOfBirth` and `DateOfRegistration`. Implementing both of them separately as two different Values makes a lot of sense. That was easy, great.

Now, let's assume in an application `Users` can participate in `Projects`. A project can have multiple `members` and a single user who founded (owns) it.

So both `ProjectMembers` and the `ProjectOwner` are `Users` under the hood.

There are two ways to implement this functionality in `Project`:

A: Strong typing - Create classes `ProjectMember` and `ProjectOwner` which then "act" as value objects. Either let them work as a wrapper or even extend the `User` class.

B: Lazy approach - Simply name methods and parameters according to the desired behavior/expectations and push `User` Objects around.

In my mind, following B means dropping DDD principles.

Following A would lead to dozens of classes, many of them wouldn't do anything, but to enforce type safety.

I'm confused because compared to simple dates, users are entities or even aggregate roots and at the same time way more complex.

Is it A, B or is there a third option?

Answer (score 2):

> Following A would lead to dozens of classes, many of them wouldn't do anything, but to enforce type safety.

No, they also document distinctions you have discovered in the domain model; you may not yet understand how those distinctions affect the behavior of the model, but you've got the place holder, and the right language in place (assuming your names are drawing upon the ubiquitous language), so your domain model is more closely aligned with the business.

That ain't nothing.

> I'm confused because compared to simple dates, users are entities or even aggregate roots and at the same time way more complex.

So one thing to keep in mind -- you don't, as a habit, reference entities from outside of the aggregate that protects them.  So `ProjectOwnerId` rather than `ProjectOwner`.

For types that don't do anything interesting ( *Identifier* in particular tends to be an opaque thing that doesn't do much except compare to other identifiers ), you 
might use the same type with a bit of syntactic sugar to ensure the type safety.

For instance `Identifier<T>` gives you `Identifier<ProjectMember>` and `Identifier<ProjectOwner>` implicitly, rather than requiring that you produce distinct implementations for each spelling of Identifier